# Sort rows in decreasing order until a blank row then continue to next blank row

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, logic

I want to sort rows in a decreasing order "until hitting every blank row."

I have the following code:

```
For j = 1 To 15
For i = 1 To 15

   Do Until mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0

   If mySheet.Cells(j, 2).Value > mySheet.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
       For c = 2 To 5
            temp1 = mySheet.Cells(i, c).Value
            mySheet.Cells(i, c).Value = mySheet.Cells(j, c).Value
            mySheet.Cells(j, c).Value = temp1
       Next c
   End If

   i = i + 1
   Loop

Next i
Next j
```

The If statement swaps the rows in decreasing order by comparing the 2nd number of the row.

What went wrong is the Do Until Loop. I'd like to keep checking/swapping the rows until it hits a blank row, but continue to check/swapping for the rows after a blank row. Check, swap, stop when hitting a blank row, then check the next rows again, swap again, so on and so forth.

**EDIT** 
Here is a what's what I am trying to do: 
BEFORE:

```
Row   B           C      D       E
1     63743       734    1848    246
2     86208       900    900     974
3     --------**Empty Row**----------
4     40934       730    5643    5565
5     97734       454    54656   3345
6     73885       347    3728    9934
7     --------**Empty Row**----------
8     34355       998    3884    3299
9     98438       383    43483   4399
10    19874       454    53439   3499
11    --------**Empty Row**----------
```

AFTER:

```
Row   B           C      D       E
1     86208       900    900     974
2     63743       734    1848    246
3     --------**Empty Row**----------
4     97734       454    54656   3345
5     73885       347    3728    9934
6     40934       730    5643    5565
7     --------**Empty Row**----------
8     98438       383    43483   4399
9     34355       998    3884    3299
10    19874       454    53439   3499
11    --------**Empty Row**----------
```

My `If` compares the values in Column B, and sorts rows in a decreasing order. I could not figure out how to make a while loop so to stop sorting when hitting a blank row, but then continue comparing/sorting for the next couple rows after a blank row. Note I would not know how many rows there are before a blank row.

**EDIT 2** 
BEFORE:

```
Row   A   B           C      D       E
1     A    63743       734    1848    246
2     B    86208       900    900     974
3     -------------**Empty Row**----------
4     C    40934       730    5643    5565
5     D    97734       454    54656   3345
6     E    73885       347    3728    9934
7     -------------**Empty Row**----------
8     F    34355       998    3884    3299
9     G    98438       383    43483   4399
10    H    19874       454    53439   3499
11    -------------**Empty Row**----------
```

AFTER:

```
Row   A   B           C      D       E
1     B   86208       900    900     974
2     A   63743       734    1848    246
3     -------------**Empty Row**----------
4     D   97734       454    54656   3345
5     E   73885       347    3728    9934
6     C   40934       730    5643    5565
7     -------------**Empty Row**----------
8     G   98438       383    43483   4399
9     F   34355       998    3884    3299
10    H   19874       454    53439   3499
11    -------------**Empty Row**----------
```

Comment: Now your question is finally clear! I will give it one more shot!

Comment: I have upvoted this now because this is starting to look like a well asked question.... And I think the answer is now what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as it stands can never terminate, because the variable you are checking,

```
Do Until mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0
```

if not changed in any of what follows:

```
If mySheet.Cells(j, 2).Value > mySheet.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
   For c = 2 To 5
        temp1 = mySheet.Cells(i, c).Value
        mySheet.Cells(i, c).Value = mySheet.Cells(j, c).Value
        mySheet.Cells(j, c).Value = temp1
   Next c
End If
```

You loop your `c` from 2 to 5, so `Cells(i,1)` is never touched.

This is so fundamental that it's a little bit hard to understand what you were really trying to do, but I'll have a shot at it.

It seems that you want each of columns 2 to 5 (maybe 1 to 5) to be sorted with a bubble sort - check two adjacent cells, move the smaller one to the top, keep going to the bottom of the column. You don't state whether each column has the same length, so I am going to assume it doesn't.

We should be able to sort one column at a time as follows (this is not the most efficient algorithm but it's true to your intention, I think):

```
Sub sortMyColumns()
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim numRows As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim lastCell As Range

For colNum = 1 To 5
    Set lastCell = Cells(1, colNum).End(xlDown)
    numRows = lastCell.Row
    For i = 2 To numRows
        For j = numRows To i Step -1
           If Cells(j, colNum) < Cells(j - 1, colNum) Then
             temp = Cells(j - 1, colNum).Value
             Cells(j - 1, colNum).Value = Cells(j, colNum).Value
             Cells(j, colNum).Value = temp
          End If
        Next j
    Next i
Next colNum
End Sub
```

For each column, this finds the number of rows; it then starts at the bottom, and pushes the smaller number all the way to the top. It returns to the bottom, but this time only pushes up to one from the top. It continues until it gets to the last two cells - everything should now be sorted.

You may need to add some error trapping in case cells do not contain numerical values etc, but in principle this should work.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, this was not what you were looking for. I have created a second Sub which sorts columns B through E based just on the value in B - this mirrors your code example a little better, and may be what you had in mind. I am using the length of column B to find out how many rows to sort - I still don't understand clearly what your column A is doing and how testing it helps you.

If this is still not what you want, I suggest you edit your question with a simple example (screen shot) of the type "this is what my sheet starts out with", and "this is what it has to look like". Just four or five lines of the spreadsheet, and columns A through E, should be sufficient.

```
Sub sortByColumnB()
' sort cells in columns B through E
' based on the value found in B
    Dim colNum As Integer
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim lastCell As Range

    ' find the last cell in column B:
    Set lastCell = Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)
    numRows = lastCell.Row
    For i = 2 To numRows
        For j = numRows To i Step -1
           If Cells(j, 2) < Cells(j - 1, 2) Then
             ' swap around each of the cells in this row with the one above
             For colNum = 2 To 5
                 temp = Cells(j - 1, colNum).Value
                 Cells(j - 1, colNum).Value = Cells(j, colNum).Value
                 Cells(j, colNum).Value = temp
             Next colNum
          End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

I ran this code on the following dummy spreadsheet:

[image]

And it resulted in the following output:

[image]

As you can see, column A was untouched, and each row in columns B through E is sorted according to the key in column B. You know of course that there is a built in sort function in Excel, but I assume you had reasons for not wanting to use it...

I hope this is what you needed! If it isn't, then please update your question with and example of "I want THIS to turn into THAT".

**EDIT 3**
Your latest update to the question plus the comment to my solution finally makes it clear what you intend to do. Since we can't really know we have reached the last block until we "fall off the edge", I have modified the code so it has an infinite loop with an error trap (that is generated when you try to go beyond the bottom of the spreadsheet). I tested this with blank row all the way (including blank in column A - note the code no longer uses column A at all):

```
Sub keepSorting()
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim firstRow, lastRow As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer

' loop around the algorithm we had earlier, but only for the 'non-empty blocks of rows'
firstRow = 1
lastRow = [B1].End(xlDown).Row

On Error GoTo allDone

While True ' break out of the loop when we throw error
' sort from firstRow to lastRow:
    For i = firstRow + 1 To lastRow
        For j = lastRow To i Step -1
           If Cells(j, 2) > Cells(j - 1, 2) Then
             ' swap around each of the cells in this row with the one above
             For colNum = 1 To 5
                 temp = Cells(j - 1, colNum).Value
                 Cells(j - 1, colNum).Value = Cells(j, colNum).Value
                 Cells(j, colNum).Value = temp
             Next colNum
          End If
        Next j
    Next i
    firstRow = Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    lastRow = Cells(firstRow, 2).End(xlDown).Row

Wend

allDone:
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

It turns THIS:

[image]

into THIS:

[image]

Note - the `On Error Resume Next` is there because finding the `lastRow` when `firstRow` is at the bottom of the sheet generates an error; but since we're done by that time, we just need to exit the while loop...

Comment: I apologize for now stating what I want clearly. Every row has the same column and the reason I am using `mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0` is because the entire row will be empty so I just pick `1` to be the checking column. Thank you very much for the effort, but I ran your code and it does not work...

Comment: "Every row has the same column"? What does that mean? I am looking at your code again, and maybe you are trying to sort columns B through E based on the value you find in B. And you do so until you get to the last cell with a value in it. The code I provided sorts each of columns B through E in turn. Quite different. I will edit my answer - leaving the original code intact and providing a second snippet that does what I now think you want...

Comment: I edited my question and gave an example of what I am trying to do. My problem is I don't know how to skip a blank row and let program continue running to compare/swapping the rows that are after a blank row. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: I see what you did there! I didn't realize my if statement could be written in this way. I was never familiar with .Row or .End command in VBA, but I think it's time to learn them now! Thank you so much!

Comment: You learnt something about VBA, as well as about asking good questions... It's a life long journey. You're very welcome!

Comment: @Flrois, your code is not running correctly. Could you please check it again fix it a bit? Thank you.

Comment: What are the symptoms of "not running correctly"? Be specific

Comment: I did not check carefully yesterday, but your code is actually only sorting/comparing the values for the first group that is before the first blank row. After the first blank row, rows are no longer sorting.

Comment: My screenshot shows otherwise.... This was using exactly what you had shown. Is there a gap in column A as well?

Comment: Yes there is a gap in Column A as well. The row is "Entirely blank" throughout all columns in the same row. I am so bad at wording this.... I am sorry!

Comment: It is an easy fix - but not from my phone. Will update soon. Don't worry you are learning how hard it is to explain a problem. When you can't explain a problem, neither you nor anyone else can solve it. As you get better at explaining you will get better at solving your own problems - they are closely related.

Comment: I just learnt from my supervisor five minutes ago the Column A has to move along as well haha... See Edit2! I promise this is the last time I will change the requirement.... Sorry!

Comment: Fixed . I just did `For colNum = 1 To 5` instead of `2 To 5`.

Comment: Instead of looping trough columns (For colNum = 1 To 5) you could swap the all rows using Rows instead of Cells:
temp = Rows(j - 1).Value
Rows(j - 1).Value = Rows(j).Value
Rows(j).Value = temp

Comment: @pnunes540 - note that it is not clear that the entire row should be swapped - just the values in columns A through E (originally, just B through E). But if one wanted to sort everything, then your method looks more efficient. However, it would require Excel to move the values in 16384 cells instead of 5 - so while it might be fewer VBA statements, I'm not sure it really saves that much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but if you want to keep your nested `For` approach the first thing you need to do is find out how many rows there are before you hit a blank.

```
Dim lngTotalRows As Long

lngTotalRows = 0

While Cells(lngTotalRows + 1, 1) <> ""
    lngTotalRows = lngTotalRows + 1
Wend
```

Now that you have that, you can just basically use your existing code replacing your 15 with lngTotalRows.  You do have a couple small problems with your loops though...

Your outer loop should be:

```
For j = 1 to lngTotalRows - 1
```

Your inner loop should be:

```
For i = j + 1 to lngTotalRows
```

If you look at a couple specific example you will probably see why.  You are comparing your outer loop cell to each cell **after** it, so the first time through the loop our first cell will have `j = 1` (so the **cell in Row 1**) and we are comparing it to every row after that, so we start at `j + 1` (**which is Row 2**), then we look at row 3, row 4 and so on.  When the outer loop is looking at **Row 10** the inner loop will just look at the values between **Row 11** and the end of the sort range.

The outer loop ends at `lngTotalRows - 1` because the inner loop will be looking at the cell after that one which will be the last cell in the range.

See if you can implement that in your existing code.  If things aren't behaving as you expect use breakpoints and inspect the values while you step through the code.  It can be very enlightening.  Also you can use `Debug.Print` statements in your code to output values to the immediate window to help track down problems.

Comment: Thank you. But the while-loop is not working still. 
`While Cells(lngTotalRows + 1, 1) <> ""
    lngTotalRows = lngTotalRows + 1
Wend

For j = 1 To lngTotalRows - 1
   For i = j + 1 To IngTotalRows
       
       If mySheet.Cells(j, 2).Value > mySheet.Cells(i, 2).Value Then

           For c = 2 To 5
                temp1 = mySheet.Cells(i, c).Value
                mySheet.Cells(i, c).Value = mySheet.Cells(j, c).Value
                mySheet.Cells(j, c).Value = temp1
           Next c
       End If
       
    Next i
Next j`

Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Well my while loop is looking at column 1 -- that's the , 1) <> "" part.  So you'd change that to ,  2) <> "" to look at column 2 to look at that one.  Also I was assuming you were sorting one single big range that ended with a blank--this routine will only sort the first one.